# How to print decimal points in cobol?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I want the data to be in decimal format in the spool. How can I print the data with decimal points. I have used

```
Pic 99v99
```

for my data-definition, but it is not showing a decimal-point in the result when I `DISPLAY` it.

`12.34` for the value of my data is displayed as `1234`

Comment: next time you are around, don't forget to accept @petit.t's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `V` in `99V99` is just an "invisible" decimal-point that sets the correct alignment for any fixed-point-operations. It has the advantage that it doesn't take up any additional memory. If you want a comma that is displayed use a `PIC`-clause like `99.99` which will

- take up one more byte
- only work with `USAGE DISPLAY`, not on `COMP`-fields

Note: When using `DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA` you have to change the `PIC`-clause accordingly to: `PIC 99,99`

Comment: I think `PIC 99.99` will work with unsigned COMP variables as well. If you practice the case with a signed COMP variable, then you need to change your target variable data type to `PIC -99.99`.

Comment: This is not part of the question but would be interesting to consider: How about dealing with S9.9? The S is invalid with "."